# Can't see customize toolbar icon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, customization, toolbar

I want a icon in the Browsertoolbar - that works. See image one

http://s18.postimage.org/njeyj7ekn/Neues_Bild.png

But why I can't see the icon in the icon selection box?

http://s18.postimage.org/pzgrx1wnb/Neues_Bild_1.png

I get only the toolbar icons.

Here are my code snippets:

XUL:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
      <toolbarbutton id="megxbar-ide-button" label="&MegxBarSidebar.label;" class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional" tooltiptext="&MegxBarSidebar.label;" observes="viewSidebar_MegxBar" />
   </toolbarpalette>
```

CSS:

```
@namespace url('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul');

#megxbar-ide-button {
  list-style-image: url(chrome://MegxBar/skin/megxbar24.png);

}

toolbar[iconsize="small"] #megxbar-ide-button {

    list-style-image: url(chrome://MegxBar/skin/megxbar16.png);

   }
```

And I have one more question. How could I set the icon per default on that positon of picture number 1? I mean, I start the browser an see the icon of the extension after the first restart after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your style file only applies to the browser window, not to the customization window. So the icon shows up with the default styles.

You can simply add a [style overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#style) to your `chrome.manifest` file:

```
style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://MegxBar/skin/ff-overlay.css
```